# Proving tangent of a curve is equal to tangent of tangent of upper and lower bounds at the same point.

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x$ in an open interval containing $a$, and that $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ have the same tangent $L$ at the common point $x=a$. Prove that $L$ is also the tangent to $g(x)$ at $x=a$.

---

Since $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$,

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \le \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) \le \lim_{x\to 0}h(x)\\
f'(x) \le g'(x) \le h'(x)$

Since $f'(a)=h'(a)$

$f'(a)=g'(a)=h'(a) $

---

I feel like there is something that I am doing wrong. I also think that I'm missing out on some crucial steps. Please advise on what I should do.

Comment: Your second line is definitely wrong. Look at the correct definition of derivative at a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $f$ and $h$ have same tangent at point $a$ means that $f(a) =h(a) $ and $f'(a) =h'(a) $. From the given conditions we then have $f(a) =g(a) =h(a) $ and therefore $$f(x) - f(a) \leq g(x) - g(a) \leq h(x) - h(a) $$ Dividing the above with $(x-a) $ will either keep the inequality in same or reverse direction according as $x>a$ or $x<a$ and lets take the case $x>a$. Then we have $$\frac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} \leq \frac{g(x) - g(a)} {x-a} \leq \frac{h(x) - h(a)} {x-a} $$ and taking limit as $x\to a^{+} $ and using Squeeze Theorem we get $f'(a) = g'_{+} (a) =h'(a) $. Similarly considering the case $x<a$ we get $f'(a) =g'_{-} (a) =h'(a) $. Therefore $g'(a) $ exists and is equal to the common value of $f'(a) $ and $h'(a) $. Thus graph of $g$ will also have the same tangent as those of $f$ and $h$ at point $a$.